# HTML5 Canvas using React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobile, react-native

What is the right way to use html5 canvas in react native?
Do I need to use webview, some plugin or can I just use plain html canvas in react native code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a module
[React-Native-Canvas](https://github.com/iddan/react-native-canvas)

Maybe try it out?

Comment: Unfortunately this repo is unmaintained